# Make a copy of a specific row using its serial in the same table in Sqlite without looping

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I have a Table with each row containing a serial number.I know I can loop through all the Table to find the serial then extract the data in variables and reinsert it but isn't there a more efficient way since I have a lot of data and I just want to make a copy of the row since I know its Serial number.

Any one liner would make my day :).

Comment: is that serial number indexed as a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Yes each row has INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT. If you have a solution considering it not unique I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [INSERT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) can take a query to specify the data to be inserted. So you can simply use that query to get the desired row.
Please note that the serial number itself is not to be copied:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(col2, col3, [...])
SELECT col2, col3, [...]
FROM MyTable
WHERE SerialNumber = ?;
```

In Android, you can execute such statements with [execSQL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)):

```java
db.execSQL("INSERT ... SELECT ...");
```

Comment: From documentation: **execSQL(String sql)
Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.** . Will it really execute? I can't myself test it right now.

Comment: INSERT does not return data.

Comment: This looks like a really efficient solution I tried it but got a   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: .I tried inserting the columns like so "+database.col+" but still same error

Comment: Here the compiled code`db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+data.Table+ "("+data.col1+","+data.col2+","+data.col3+","+data.col4+")\n‌​" + "SELECT "+data.col1+","+data.col2+","+data.col3+","+data.col4+",\n" + "FROM "+data.Table+"\n" + "WHERE SerialNumber '"+serial+"'");'@CL

Comment: Newlines do not matter in SQL (you can use spaces instead), you you have to correctly use commas and `=`.

Comment: Thanks I've tried it once more and it worked only problem its highly scripted however thats maybe because I don't use execSQL too often only in database.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a query like this (considering serial_number not unique):

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_1, column_2, serial_number....)
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE serial_number = YOUR_SERIAL_NUMBER;
```

**Edit:**

In Java, it will be something like:

```
String sql = "SELECT *" +
                     " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                     " WHERE " + serial_number + " = " + serial_number + "";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    if (cursor !=null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

String value_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_NAME_1"));
String value_2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_NAME_2"));
String value_3 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_NAME_3"));

cursor.close();

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

cv.put("COLUMN_NAME_1", value_1);
cv.put("COLUMN_NAME_2", value_2);
cv.put("COLUMN_NAME_3", value_3);

db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
```

I'm assuming that your serial number is Integer. If it's a string value, please wrap up your serial_number value with '...'

```
" WHERE " + serial_number + " = '" + serial_number + "'";
```

Comment: Exactly I want to do it like that but if you noticed I am using android studio and don't know how to implement it in java.

Comment: Yes i just want to see your code in java for ex db.insert(tablename,null,contentvalues); is how I insert in a Table

Comment: He wanted a more efficient way, i.e., `rawQuery`.

Comment: Please post an answer if you can. Would be helpful for me too. :) @CL.

Comment: Its a good way so I don't have to loop Table but as I said I have a lot of data and extracting then inserting is not something I'd like to do alot.